# file_get_contents('php://input') returns empty

Tags: php, xml

Sending xml data from one server to another server using `file_get_contents('php://input')` returns empty. I'm sending the test xml to ensure the remote file will process incoming xml streams.

```
$xmlcontent  = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<english>\n<amount>\n4500.22 dollars\n</amount>\n</english>";
$url = "https://www.example.info/xmlprocessor";
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => "Content-type: text/xml",
        'content' => $xmlcontent
    ));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$response = file_get_contents($url,false,$context);
//$fp = fopen($url,'r',false,$context);
//fpassthru($fp);
//fclose($fp);
```

remote site(https://www.example.info/xmlprocessor)

```
$response = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents('php://input'));
//$response = simplexml_load_string(fopen('php://stdin','r'));
//$response = file_get_contents('php://input');
//$response = $_POST;
$processed = json_encode($response);
$results = $db->exec("INSERT INTO example (date,data) VALUES('$time','$processed')");
```

I've tried all that are commented out as well as different header strings and using `'xml' => xmlcontent` in the $opts. Additionally, I've tried using curl which did not even run the remote script.

Comment: You're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: I'm acutally putting them in a table during testing so I can see multiple returns from the actual server that will send data. Once that phase is complete, I will not do anything with storing data. I will be contacting another server with commands based on certain xml data received to perform an action.

Comment: Do you even know if the request is getting sent? Try it with HTTP instead of HTTPS; do a packet trace on the far end to be sure.

Comment: The other server is receiving the request. The script there runs and adds empty data to the database. I get false with simplexml_load_string and {} without using the xml reader from the json conversion.